# JsonLocalisation and WPF cannot find my translation files

Tags: json, wpf, localization, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

My app runs in WPF and Android (Windows Phone later) with mvvmcross as framework. I implemented localization with JsonLocalisation like the Babel ([N21](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkxHtbJ_Tlk)) example and it is working fine in Android. But whatever I try in WPF I get this message;

> mvx:Warning:  0,22 Language file could not be loaded for Danish.SettingsViewModel - 
>   FileNotFoundException: Unable to find resource file MyAppResources/Text/Danish/SettingsViewModel.json
>   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.JsonLocalisation.MvxContentJsonDictionaryTextProvider.
>   LoadJsonFromResource(String namespaceKey, String typeKey, String resourcePath) at >Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.JsonLocalisation.MvxTextProviderBuilder.LoadResources(String >whichLocalisationFolder)"

Stuart says in his video tutorial that the json translation files must be included as "Content" and not copied to the [output folder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkxHtbJ_Tlk#t=1336) - like;

[image: Build action]

But looking at the compiled executable with "dotPeek" doesn't reveal the files.

Am I missing something obvious? Any hints would be highly appreciated. Even confirmation from somebody who has JsonLocalisation working in WPF would be nice.

**EDIT:**

Well, I tried this code in my WPF mainWindow. I understand this call is used internally in MvxWPFResourceLoader.

```
public MainWindow()
{
  ....

  //This return null without exceptions.
  var t = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("MyAppResources/Text/Danish/SettingsViewModel.json", UriKind.Relative));

  //This throwns an IOException; Cannot locate resource 'thisdoesnotexist/text/danish/settingsviewmodel.json'.
  var y = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("ThisDoesNotExist/Text/Danish/SettingsViewModel.json", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

It seems when the path if wrong an exception is thrown. When it is correct it just returns null!!?! I am a bit puzzled, any ideas?

Best regards

Comment: Try setting the "copy to" to always - see Babel.Wpf in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Babel/Babel.Wpf/Babel.Wpf.csproj#L125

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for such fast answer (and for mvvmcross!).

The link you provided is to a Babel solution with a WPF sample - exactly what I needed. I mistakenly used the one [from N21](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/n21-internationalisation-i18n-n1-days.html) without WPF sample :-)

Anyway, when looking at the sample I noticed that the json files must be included as 'Resource' and not 'Content'. That made all the difference - hurray!

[image]

Best regards